# Why is $-2 = -64 \cdot r^{-5} \implies \frac 1{32} = \frac{1}{r^5}$?

Tags: exponential-function, diophantine-equations

What are the steps Khan Academy uses to simplify from $-2 = -64 \cdot r^{-5}$ to $\frac 1{32} = \frac{1}{r^5}$?

Comment: 1) Divide both sides by $-64$
2) rewrite $r^{-5}=\frac{1}{r^5}$

Comment: thanks I clearly need more coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Divide both sides by $-64$ to yield

$$ \frac{-2}{-64} = r^{-5} $$

and, by definition (and after simplifying the fraction on the left),

$$ \frac{1}{32} = \frac{1}{r^5}. $$